# MySQL get row count and group by month to column header

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have this result

```
Name    |  January  |    Feb    |   March
Adrian  |     12    |           |    
Adrian  |           |     15    |    
Adrian  |           |           |     9
Bryan...
```

Using this query

```
SELECT
    user.first_name AS name,
CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '1' THEN count(order.id) END AS January,
CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '2' THEN count(order.id) END AS January,
CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '3' THEN count(order.id) END AS January
FROM
    order
        JOIN user ON user.id = order.create_by
WHERE
    order.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    order.create_by,
    MONTH(order.create_datetime)
ORDER BY
    user.first_name
```

I need it to be, but I am not sure what I should do

```
Name      | January |   Feb   |   March   |TOTAL
Adrian    | 12      |    15   |     9
Bryan
```

And a TOTAL at the end.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.first_name AS NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(O.create_datetime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS January,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(O.create_datetime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(O.create_datetime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS March
FROM ORDER O
JOIN USER U ON U.id = O.create_by
WHERE O.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY O.create_by
ORDER BY U.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your aggregation logic as below :

```
SELECT
    user.first_name AS name,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '1' THEN (order.id) END) AS JAN,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '2' THEN (order.id) END) AS FEB,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(order.create_datetime) = '3' THEN (order.id) END) AS MAR
FROM
    order
        JOIN user ON user.id = order.create_by
WHERE
    order.create_datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    user.first_name
ORDER BY
    user.first_name
    ;
```